# update_attribute updates only once

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I entered `rails console` of my application and performed following statements:

```
order = Order.find(2)
order.update_attribute(:start_at, Time.new)
```

ActiveRecord composed following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE orders
SET
    start_at = '2000-01-01 14:23:00',
    updated_at = '2014-07-16 10:30:59'
WHERE
    orders.id = 2
```

Now I execute the same `update_attribute` method with same parameters again and again and get

```
UPDATE orders SET updated_at = '2014-07-16 10:33:52' WHERE orders.id = 2
UPDATE orders SET updated_at = '2014-07-16 10:34:11' WHERE orders.id = 2
UPDATE orders SET updated_at = '2014-07-16 10:37:19' WHERE orders.id = 2
```

Nothing is updated except `updated_at` field!

Comment: are there any callbacks on your `Order` model?

Comment: doesn't happen in my console... though I use Rails 4, might be a bug.

Comment: You didn't pose a question? FYI: for this sort of update, you might want to use `touch` instead: `order.touch(:start_at)`.

Answer (score 0):

Some explain methods what you use (all from doc):

```
update_attribute(name, value) <= v2.3.8
```

Updates a single attribute and saves the record without going through the normal validation procedure.

```
update_attribute(name, value) >= 4.0.0
```

Updates a single attribute and saves the record. This is especially useful for boolean flags on existing records. Also note that

- Validation is skipped.
- Callbacks are invoked.
- ***updated_at/updated_on column is updated if that column is available.***
- ***Updates all the attributes that are dirty in this object.***

And what you try:

update only `updated_at` is updated because column is available.

```
order.update_attribute(:start_at, Time.new)
```

dirty attributes:

```
order.start_at = Time.new
```

again:

```
order.update_attribute(:start_at, Time.new)
```

Now column start_at updated.